# How do I hide the FINISH and CANCEL buttons on SharePoint survey?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, survey

I am working with SP online. And i have written a custom code "JavaScript". I am primarily looking to hide those Two button's from my SharePoint survey list as mentioned above in the title. 
Below is the code i have tried and no luck yet. (I replace 000 with the button id):

document.getElementById("000").style.visibility='hidden';

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
            //Hiding the form toolbar
        $('.ms-formtoolbar').hide();
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page in designer and add below code after ContentPlaceHolderMain:

here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
 if (x.item(i).type=="button"&&x.item(i).value=="Finish")
 {x.item(i).style.display = "none"};
 }
}
 </script>
```